# Photoswipe pinch to zoom issue in Phonegap application

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, photoswipe

I have a simple application HTML5 + JS (JQM) compiled with Phonegap. I'm using Photoswipe to show some pictures and I'm not able to zoom images when pinching these pictures.
Anyone else facing this problem?

Comment: Is it just not working at all? Or what is it giving you?

Comment: It just doesn't recognize the pinch gesture.

Comment: Are any errors being generated? Can you post part of your code so I can see how you are trying to implement it?

Comment: It's just a list of images wrapped in anchor tags. I get no error. Maybe it's something in the configuration but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you including [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) and [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)? Take a look at [this](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/issues/332).

Comment: still not working. Photoswipe has its own pinch to zoom feauture, so i  guess I'm missing some Phonegap configuration.